# Creating JSON object from language file

Tags: c++, json, file, c++11

I'm having a translation file which looks like this:

```
#: this is just some comment
msgid ""
"this is a line.\n"
"this is a newline.\n"
"this is another newLine".
msgstr ""
"this can be filled in.\n"
"or left blank."
#: just another comment
msgid "Pizza"
msgstr ""
```

As you can see `msgid` can be multiline or singlelined. Same goes for `msgstr`.

All my translation files looks like this. How would i create a json object containing two keys like this using the above data example:

```
[
    {
        "msgid": "this is a line.\nthis is a newline.\nthis is another newLine.",
        "msgstr": "this can be filled in.\n or left blank."
    },
    {
        "msgid": "Pizza",
        "msgstr": ""
    }
]
```

I have access to a json libary which i know how to use. I'm struggling with the for(each) loop looping through the data.

At the moment i have this piece of code:

```
std::ifstream input(findFile("language.po"));
Json::Value jsonRoot = Json:arrayValue;
for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); )
{
    Json::Value Translation = Json::objectValue;
    if(line.find("msgid") == 0) {
        //messageId found
        Translation["msgid"] = line;
    } else if(line.find("msgstr") == 0) {
        //translated string was found
        Translation["msgstr"] = line;
    }
    jsonRoot.append(Translation);
}
```

Yet this creates a new json array for every line which i do not want.

At this moment the current output (not tested) should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "msgid": ""
    },
    {
        "msgstr": ""
    },
    {
        "msgid": "Pizza"
    },
    {
        "msgstr": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you include your current output state from this routine in your question?

Comment: @Quirk I've did so. It's not much being printed now as i only check if string starts with `"msgid"` or `"msgstr"` which are those 4 lines

Comment: What JSON library are you actually using?

Comment: I think OP is using [Jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).

Comment: I'm using the package: `libjsoncpp-dev` on ubuntu

Comment: i think anything you'll get will be a fragile hack as your "translation file" is ambiguous

Comment: @self: in what way?  Seems fairly solid to me. The only ambiguity would be if an un-prefixed quoted line is encountered before the 1st 'msgid' line is encountered, and I suspect that will not be the case, but even if it happens it is easy to handle by just ignoring the line.

Comment: I wonder why there's a downvote as this seems to me like a good question provided with some examples and example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is adding each line to the array, regardless of the content of each line.  What you need is a state machine so you only add completed objects to the array, you need to append continuation lines to previous lines until you reach the next field start, and you need to parse the lines to remove the line prefixes and quotes.

Try something more like this:

```
std::ifstream input(findFile("language.po").string());

std::string msgid, msgstr;
std::string *field = NULL;
std::string::size_type start, end;

Json::Value jsonRoot = Json::arrayValue;

for( std::string line; std::getline( input, line ); )
{
    if (line.compare(0, 1, "#") == 0)
        continue;

    if (line.compare(0, 6, "msgid ") == 0)
    {
        if (!msgid.empty())
        {
            Json::Value Translation = Json::objectValue;
            Translation["msgid"] = msgid;
            Translation["msgstr"] = msgstr;
            jsonRoot.append(Translation);
        }

        msgid.clear();
        msgstr.clear();
        field = &msgid;
        start = 6;
    }
    else if (!field)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if (line.compare(0, 7, "msgstr ") == 0)
    {
        field = &msgstr;
        start = 7;
    }
    else
    {
        start = 0;
    }

    start = line.find('\"', start);
    if (start == std::string::npos)
        continue;

    ++start;
    end = line.find('\"', start);
    if (end != std::string::npos)
        *field += line.substr(start, end-start);
    else
        *field += line.substr(start);
}

if (!msgid.empty())
{
    Json::Value Translation = Json::objectValue;
    Translation["msgid"] = msgid;
    Translation["msgstr"] = msgstr;
    jsonRoot.append(Translation);
}
```

Comment: I see Line 5 is missing a double `::` And somehow i may not use findFile from boost with ifstream? `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(boost::filesystem::path)’`

Comment: i've added `.c_str()` to the path and it worked :) as ifstream wants a string :) hmm let's view the results now :D!

Comment: @Baklap4: The `ifstream` declaration was copied from your example, which you said was already running, just not doing what you wanted. In an ycase, don't you mean [`string()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/path.htm#string) instead of `c_str()`?  [`boost::filesystem::path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/path.htm) does not have a `c_str()` method.

Comment: Hmm strange as it does compile and run with `c_str()`

Comment: @Baklap4: Nevermind, I was looking at old boost documentation. I now see [`c_str()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#c_str) in the latest documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a simple state machine:

```
enum class State { INIT, ID, STR } state = State::INIT;

std::string buffer;

while (!end_of_file()) {
   auto s = get_next_line();

   if (is_comment(s)) {
      // do nothing

   } else if (is_msgid(s)) {

      if (state != State::STR) {
         buffer += s; // depending on how you read a line, you may have to add EOL here

      } else {
         put_msgid_into_json(buffer);
         buffer = s;
      }
      state = State::ID;

   } else if (is_msgstr(s)) {

      if (state != State::ID) {
         buffer += s; // depending on how you read a line, you may have to add EOL here

      } else {
         put_msgstr_into_json(buffer);
         buffer = s;
      }
      state = State::STR;

   }
}

if (state == State::ID) {
  put_msgid_into_json(buffer);
} else if (state == State::STR) {
  put_msgstr_into_json(buffer);
}
```